# Data not getting pushed into firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase

So this is my first time with android studio and firebase. I have written a code which takes latitude longitude from the user in EditText field and plots it in the map.
I have connected the firebase and done everything yet still the data is not getting pushed into fierbase. My main activity is follows. 
I am displaying Minimal code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnproceed =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnproceed);
    mDatabase =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    editTextName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextLatitude=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextLatitude);
    editTextLongitude=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextLongitude);
    btnsave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnproceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

private void saveUserInformation(){
    String name =editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    double latitude= Double.parseDouble(editTextLatitude.getText().toString().trim());
    double longitude= Double.parseDouble(editTextLongitude.getText().toString().trim());
    UserInformation userInformation=new UserInformation(name,latitude,longitude);
    mDatabase.child("Users").setValue(userInformation);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){

    if(view==btnproceed){
        finish();
    }
    if (view==btnsave){
        saveUserInformation();
        editTextName.getText().clear();
        editTextLatitude.getText().clear();
        editTextLongitude.getText().clear();
    }
}
```

I have setup firebase rules to be where:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Still the data is not getting pushed into firebase. Let me know if you need me to show more code.
[image]

Firebase is showing active user still no data is being received.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing code with the Realtime Database API, but you're looking for the data in the Firestore data viewer.  Use the Realtime Database data viewer instead.

Realtime Database and Firestore are completely different products.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when your on Console.Firebase.com your in RealTime Database instead of Cloud FireStore. [As seen in the picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp8f0.png)